# Downloading a remote image file to local file storage

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble downloading a remote file using node js.

The file is a large image and can only be accessed using an api request and authorization header.

I need to use node js to do the following

1. Access the asset Url using the Authorization Bearer token
2. Save the file to local file storage.

How can I do that using node js?

I tried doing

```
request.get({url: aurl, encoding: "binary"}).pipe(fs.writeFileSync('./marvel-web/dist/images/image_9.png'));
```

I'm missing the Authorization header.

I also want to do all of this synchronously not async.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the authorization to be set, in the options object of request, put:

```
{
    url: aurl,
    encoding: "binary,
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.